# How to suppress function output in python

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, arguments

Suppose I have a very simple function:

```
def myFunction(arg1, arg2):
    return arg1, arg2
```

Now if I only want to access the second argument, can do I something like:

```
none, arg2 = myFunction(arg1, arg2)
```

?

Comment: @AswinMurugesh since sometimes he might need the other argument as well, but other times it is not needed

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, yes you can do something like that. Exactly that, actually.

Assign the argument you want to ignore to a name you then simply not use anywhere else. The `_` name is often used:

```
_, arg2 = myFunction(arg1, arg2)
```

The `_` name is just a convention, but most Python developers understand it to mean 'this variable will be ignored by the rest of the code, it is just there to fulfill a tuple assignment'.

Alternatively, index or slice the output:

```
arg2 = myFunction(arg1, arg2)[-1]
```

or for a function with more than two return values:

```
arg2, arg3 = returnsMoreThanTwo(arg1, arg2)[-2:]
```

but if you wanted to ignore an argument in the middle somewhere, the `_` assignment is best. You can use it multiple times without penalty:

```
arg1, _, _, arg4 = returnsFourArguments(arg1, arg2)
```

Comment: Or where missing out a lot of stuff in the middle...`first_and_something = operator.itemgetter(0, 60)` then `first, something = first_and_something(returnsWhateverArguments(arg1, arg2))` or whatever...

Comment: @JonClements: In such cases, just assigning the output to a local, then picking out specific indices would be a little more readable. Unless you need to do this for 3 or more different function calls. Then the `itemgetter()` approach is fair game. :-P

Answer (score 4):

```
_, arg2 = myFunction(arg1, arg2)
```

Comment: Who downvoted this? It's a valid, correct answer. It's the same as Martijn's but was posted only a few seconds after.

Comment: Even more. At the moment I have posted his answer, Martijn's text was different from what it's now.

Comment: A downvote and a delete vote... wow

Comment: @JonClements 2 downvotes, actually.

Comment: @Ellioh: but it did include an explanation of *why* `_` can be used. Not that I voted on your post..

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's maybe a reason not to upvote, but not a valid reason to downvote imho.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: agree. You explained the details, and I have nothing against it. I just can't understand those who downvoted.

Comment: @Joe: I entirely agree with that; I just wanted to clarify that my answer wasn't quite *exactly* the same. :-)

Comment: +1 from me. Actually, I've seen this rate of meaningless downvotes only in `python` questions. Never seen something like this in `postgresql` or `sql-server`. Don't know why. OTOH, it works for upvotes too - once I had answer about how to join list into string (like `' '.join(a)`) with 11 upvotes!!! To get 11 upvotes in `sql-server` section I have to create something really cool :)

Comment: @RomanPekar Yep, answers with most research effort and knowledge put in rarely exceeds +3/+4. And simple onliners can bump to +11 with ease :)

Comment: @RomanPekar: sad, but true. When your answer contains some kind of a research, it has little chance of getting +11. And this completely trivial answer has already brought me +5-2 = 46 reputation. :-D

Comment: You want really ridiculous upvoting? This question is actually a duplicate (I suggest people vote to close this question). The accepted answer there has +40 upvotes.